# Computing degree of map $f: S^n\to S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Compute the degree of map $f: S^n\to S^n$, where $f$ is defined by$$f(x_0,\ldots x_i,\ldots x_j,\ldots x_n) =(x_0,\ldots x_j,\ldots x_i\ldots x_n)$$
>   which is an exchange of $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Can we find this general formula? Considering the case where $n=2$ or $3$, $f$ has degree $-1$ since it is a composition of rotation and reflection. (Am I right?) However is it generally true for $S^n$?

Thank you!

Comment: Remember that the degree of a map is multiplicative, that is, if $f:S_n\to S_n$ is continuous, then $\deg(f\circ f)=\deg(f)\cdot \deg(f)$. This narrows down your options significantly.  It is also worth noting that continuous maps on spheres are complete homotopy invariant, that is, $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$ if and only if $f,g:S^n\to S^n$ are homotopic.  Since $\deg(\operatorname{id_{S
^n}})=1$, is your map homotopic to the identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a reflection ... across the hyperplane $x_i=x_j$. (This is conjugate to reflection across a "standard" hyperplane.)